# How do I enable journal_async_commit?

Tags: mount, fstab, ext4

I'm trying to enable journal_async_commit in fstab file.
Here is what the relevant entry looks like:

```
# /dev/nvme0n1p2
UUID=c4340389-c77d-473e-8867-39b677a49f96   /           ext4        rw,lazytime,data=journal,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,commit=60    0 1
```

However, when I run `mount` command, it doesn't show in the mount options:

```
mount | grep -i nvme                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            20:28:18
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

The partition in question was created with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p2`

How do I get this to work?